# how to create a list of strings using two other lists

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

Given two lists `lst1` and `lst2`:

```
 ClearAll[lst1,lst2,lst3];
 lst1 = {"gdp", "sav evi", "sav, per capita"};
 lst2 = {"2011", "2013", "2015"};
```

I like to create the following list `lst3` in one go:

```
 lst3 = {
          "gdp 2011", "sav evi 2011", "sav, per capita 2011",
          "gdp 2013", "sav evi 2013", "sav, per capita 2013",
          "gdp 2015", "sav evi 2015", "sav, per capita 2015"
        }
```

The following does what I want:

```
 yeniLst = {"gdp " <> ToString[#], "sav evi " <> ToString[#], "sav, per capita " <> ToString[#]} & /@ lst2
```

generating:

```
 {{"gdp 2011", "sav evi 2011", "sav, per capita 2011"},
  {"gdp 2013", "sav evi 2013", "sav, per capita 2013"},
  {"gdp 2015",  "sav evi 2015", "sav, per capita 2015"}}
```

Since my actual lists `{lst1 and lst2}` are too long, I like to shorten `yeniLst` by mapping `lst1` rather than writing its elements one by one.

Any help?

Comment: Does `Transpose[Outer[StringJoin[#1, " ", #2] &, {"gdp", "sav evi", "sav, per capita"}, {"2011", "2013", "2015"}]]` do what you want?

Comment: @J.M.: Yes, it did what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Outer" will take a function as first argument and then feed it successively the first element of the first, second, third.. argument list, then the second element of all these lists e.t.c.:

Here is your example:

```
lst1 = {"gdp", "sav evi", "sav, per capita"};
lst2 = {"2011", "2013", "2015"};
Outer[#2 <> " " <> #1 &, lst2, lst1]
```

[image]

Comment: When I export the output to Excel, I see `"GDP 2011 "`, which is not proper because I like to have `GDP 2011` or `2011 GDP`. Basically, `" "` is a problem for me. How can I remove them before exporting the output to Excel?

Comment: If I export with format "XLS" and then read into Excel I do not see any ".

Comment: Also could be written: `Outer[StringRiffle[{#2, #1}] &, lst2, lst1]`

Comment: @Daniel Huber: Your example works just fine. No problem. Here is a problem I face when I use my original variable names. In MM, I produce `lst1` without strings, but when I press enter then the `lst1` turns out to be a list of strings. That is why I gave my question with string lists like `lst1 and `lst2.

Comment: @chuy: How do you do the same for 'nonstring' lists? It seems that my original MMA outputs are not string.

Comment: @chuy: Your answer worked nicely in my problematic case. Thank you for the answer. Of course, thanks also go to others.